# How to redirect to a view after successful signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
 # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
         redirect('../views/home/index.html.erb')
    end
    def  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    end
end
```

The error message I get is, `undefined method redirect in device`. What can do I to redirect to the view when it's a successful sign in.

Comment: the proper method is redirect_to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`after_sign_in_path_for` expects a route to be returned, it should not perform the redirect itself (and by the way, the method is `redirect_to`, not `redirect`).
Assuming you have a `HomeController`, your method should look something like

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    home_path
end
```